# Can Someone explain the use of `if (EP_DATA == 13)` in the code?

Tags: i2c

```c
unsigned char i2c_read(void)
{
    unsigned char i;
    lsb = SDA;
    for (i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
        EP_DATA = EP_DATA << 1;
        lsb = SDA;
        SCL = 1;
        SCL = 0;
    }

    if (EP_DATA == 13) {
        SDA = 1;
        SCL = 1;
        SCL = 0;
        SDA = 0;
        i2c_stop();
        return EP_DATA;
    }

    SDA = 0;
    SCL = 1;
    SCL = 0;
    SDA = 1;

    return EP_DATA;
}
```

I found the code on GitHub for I²C protocol for communication with DS1307 written by [Embetronicx](https://github.com/Embetronicx/Projects/blob/master/8051%20Projects/Alarm_Clock/I2C.H) and I was unable to understand the use of the if condition `if (EP_DATA == 13)`

```c
if (EP_DATA == 13) {
    SDA = 1;
    SCL = 1;
    SCL = 0;
    SDA = 0;
    i2c_stop();
    return EP_DATA
}
```

So, please can someone explain the use to that.

Comment: ASCII #13 usually means carriage return (CR), so this code seems to return as soon as a CR is received.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this can be real working code.

This is not least because there are no delays between the clock edges.  Unless the microcontroller executes these instructions at I2C compatible speeds (1940s hardware maybe?) then this will not work.

The particular `if` block you refer to can never be entered.  Because `ED_DATA` is left shifted 8 times in the preceding loop, it can never equal 13.

If I was going to guess the meaning of `13` then I might suggest that it was meant to be the numerical value of `'\r'` a carriage return, delimiting the end of a line of ASCII text.  Really though only the author of the code can tell you for certain why they wrote this.